# Designing a crossover for dual woofers and a single tweeter

Tags: filter, speakers, high-pass-filter

I recently purchased a cheap tower speaker set which has two woofers per channel. This does not have a crossover circuit as i understand and only has a filter capacitor for the tweeter.

Can a three-way crossover design work in this instance? One woofer for bass and the other for midrange.

I presume the two woofers are of the same specifications. Is it better to send the full signal to both speakers or split the workload (bass/midrange) between the two?

[image]

Comment: Fenton SHFT60B?

Comment: @greybeard, yes..

Comment: Calling the unmodified Fenton SHFT60B 3-way is - lying. 6.5 inches is marketing, one chassis they offer and designate that size has a stated "surface of air displacement" of 137 cm²: I get 132 mm.

Comment: @greybeard, looks like you own a pair. Is there any redeeming qualities to this at all. Your comments make me a remorseful buyer.

Comment: No, I don't own a pair. There are communities of audio enthusiasts, and of speaker design hobbyists. I think they don't take up an unwarranted amount of space, don't look bad (from the aesthetic side; the non-tweeters are too far apart for a D'Appolito), aren't overpriced.

Comment: What you need if the 6 dB/octave capacitor roll-off and blasting HF in the woofers isn't good enough, is a 2-way crossover. Just because there are three speakers in the cabinet does not call for a 3-way. If you have two woofers connected in parallel, you just need to account for the lower impedance of those in your crossover design. What impedances do you measure or are marked on the speakers?

Comment: FWIW, passive crossover design is a messy business. You are dealing with too many dependencies (load impedance varies greatly with frequency, output impedance of crossover the same, very difficult to examine signals and see what is causing what) - and then you have the bass port on top, which makes it worse. For the price of two more amplifier channels, you could design active crossovers before the power amp, which *considerably* simplifies things, and also makes it far easier to tune the response. If you are going to try to improve these things, this is easier and better.

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle bass isn't to not use half the cone area available to drive it.

Guessing the tweeter dome to be one inch, the cone speakers seem to be about five inches.

That is exactly the size [D'Appolito suggests](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midwoofer-tweeter-midwoofer) - using a 4th order filter, easier to build as an "active" filter.

If the cones were larger, say, 8 inches, you would still use both for bass, but feed the midrange to just one of them.

A targeted(?) modification of an existing box (enclosure+filter+drivers) is quite an undertaking.

You added as model Fenton SHFT60B, which is described as *bass reflex*.

Using just one of the drivers for bass may require modifications to the bass reflex opening: Without acoustic decoupling/separate volumes the other driver will take the role of a passive radiator even driven by a low impedance source. With separation, the volume to interact with the reflex opening is reduced.